# Save safe string with createMultipleInsertCommand in yii project

Tags: php, yii, pdo

How can i create safe string in yii, if i want to save multiple data?
This is my code:

```
$builder = Yii::app()->db->schema->commandBuilder;
$command = $builder->createMultipleInsertCommand('ewl_team_user', array(
    array('user_name'=>'record1', 'user_desc'=>'leírás','team_id'=>1),
    array('user_name'=>'record2', 'user_desc'=>'leírás','team_id'=>1),
    array('user_name'=>'record3', 'user_desc'=>'leírás','team_id'=>1),
));
```

How can i use PDO params in this code?
Where should i write this part?

```
'params'=>array(':t'=>$data)
```

Comment: Why don't you use ActiveRecord for saving data?

Comment: If you use active record for saving data, your save query will be parameterized automatically and you don't need to care about parameters.

Comment: CDbCommandBuilder#createMultipleInsertCommand does not have the "params" argument.

Comment: can you give me any solution pls?

Comment: I gave a solution in my answer. Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, [CDbCommandBuilder#createMultipleInsertCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommandBuilder#createMultipleInsertCommand-detail) does not have any `params` argument. So the better way is to use CActiveRecord for saving data. First, you need to generate Model from table entity by Gii tools. If you are not familiar with Gii, refer [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app#implementing-crud-operations). Then you can instantiate any number of objects, assign desired values to attributes, and finally save them.

Comment: Yes i read it. Thank you the answer. I know how gii works. However i want to save multiple row in sql without foreach. I would like to create one sql with yii. Here is an example with sql:INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )